# Using reflection to address a Linqed property

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection, or-designer

I'm trying to writing a generic method that will load a record of a specific type, with a specific ID.  Here's one way that works:

```
    public abstract class LinqedTable<T> where T : LinqableTable {
    public static T Get(long ID) {
        DataContext context = LinqUtils.GetDataContext<T>();
        var q = from obj in context.GetTable<T>()
                        where obj.ID == ID
                        select obj;
        return q.Single<T>();
    }
}

public abstract class LinqableTable {
    public abstract long ID { get; set; }
}
```

You can ignore the call to `LinqUtils.GetDataContext<T>()`; that's a utility function I've got to deal with the fact that I have multiple data contexts in my program.  The point is that now I can declare any of my classes as subclasses of `LinqableTable`, and I can easily instantiate a record of that table just by calling `LinqedTable<MyType>.Get(ID)`.

This has some limitations, however.  Firstly, it forces all of my tables to have an I
identity field of type `long`, named `ID`.  Secondly, because I'm using an abstract method, I am forced to go to the O/R designer and change the inheritance property of every ID field in my system to "override".

I want more flexibility than that.  So naturally, I tried reflection, and came out with the following:

```
    public abstract class LinqedTable<T> where T : LinqableTable {
    public static T Get(long ID) {
        DataContext context = LinqUtils.GetDataContext<T>();
        var q = from obj in context.GetTable<T>()
                        where obj.IDValue == ID
                        select obj;
        return q.Single<T>();
    }
}

public abstract class LinqableTable {
    internal long IDValue {
        get { return (long)IDProperty.GetValue(this, null); }
        set { IDProperty.SetValue(this, value, null); }
    }
    internal PropertyInfo IDProperty {
        get { return this.GetType().GetProperty(IDPropertyName); }
    }
    internal protected virtual string IDPropertyName {
        get { return "ID"; }
    }
}
```

Theoretically, this allows me to override the ID column name, the cast to `long` should be OK with any integral data type, and I don't need to go defining all my ID columns as `overrides`.

**BUT**

Linq doesn't like this.  On the call to `q.Single<T>();` I get a runtime error:

`The member 'EISS.Utils.LinqableTable.IDValue' has no supported translation to SQL.`

OK, today I learned that Linq does some kind of magic on the back end; it doesn't instantiate `obj` and just read the `IDValue` property.  So must be there's some attribute that needs to be set on the `IDValue` property that lets Linq do its thing.

But what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq to SQL tries to translate your linq-query into SQL, but it does not know how to translate your property to a column name in the DB.

A good explanation can be found here on SO:
[simple linq to sql has no supported translation to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332670/simple-linq-to-sql-has-no-supported-translation-to-sql)

But how to solve it, is another matter. I have with succes used the apporoach from this thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/df9dba6e-4615-478d-9d8a-9fd80c941ea2/

Or you can use dynamic query as mentioned here by scott guthrie:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links!  The first one leads to a working solution (see the solution given by CompuBoy).

Answer (score 1):

Having read these posts: [Generic Data Access using LINQ to SQL and C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/GenericL2SinCS07212008041344AM/GenericL2SinCS.aspx),
[LINQ-to-SQL: Generic Primary Key function](http://csainty.blogspot.com/2008/04/linq-to-sql-generic-primary-key.html) and 
[Calling a generic method with Type](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=29446785&threadid=29446774)

My colleague and I came up with the following digest:

We added the following method to our datacontext (in a partial class).

```
public T GetInstanceByPrimaryKey<T>(object primaryKeyValue) where T : class
{
    var table = this.GetTable<T>();
    var mapping = this.Mapping.GetTable(typeof(T));
    var pkfield = mapping.RowType.DataMembers.SingleOrDefault(d => d.IsPrimaryKey);

    if (pkfield == null)
        throw new Exception(String.Format("Table {0} does not contain a Primary Key field", mapping.TableName));

    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");

    var predicate =
        Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, pkfield.Name), Expression.Constant(primaryKeyValue)), param);

    return table.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

Then, where we need to instanciate from the type name and primary key value:

```
string name = "LinqObjectName";
int primaryKey = 123;

var dc = new YourDataContext();

Type dcType = dc.GetType();
Type type = dcType.Assembly.GetType(String.Format("{0}.{1}", dcType.Namespace, name));

MethodInfo methodInfoOfMethodToExcute = dc.GetType().GetMethod("GetInstanceByPrimaryKey");
MethodInfo methodInfoOfTypeToGet = methodInfoOfMethodToExcute.MakeGenericMethod(name);
var instance = methodInfoOfTypeToGet.Invoke(dc, new object[] { primaryKey });

return instance;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Since LINQ statements referred to a LINQ-to-SQL IQueryable are translated to SQL queries, you will have to use the AsEnumerable extension (which will in turn cause a read of all the items in the database) and do reflection-related stuff on that IEnumerable.

**EDIT**

As required here's a clarification
As specified in a comment, what I meant was something like:

```
 (from obj in context.GetTable<T>() select obj).AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.IDValue == ID)
```

Unlike a query executed on an IQueryable, which can be perfectly translated to SQL such as

```
context.GetTable().Where(x => x.Text == "Hello")
```

which gets converted to something similar to

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_MAPPED_TO_TYPE_T WHERE Text = 'Hello'
```

a query executed against an IEnumerable - in your case - will be executed by fetching all the entries of your table and then applying code-wise the specified filter.

Comment: Please clarify - perhaps with an example of the syntax you have in mind?

Comment: A think emaster means like: (from obj in context.GetTable<T>() select obj).AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.IDValue == ID)... But that is very inefficient.